# minecraft launcher 1.3.7 problem

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

```
[16:33:33 WARN]: Couldn't download https://libraries.minecraft.net/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl_util/2.9.1-nightly-20131120/lwjgl_util-2.9.1-nightly-20131120.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.7.0_40]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.ChecksummedDownloadable.download(ChecksummedDownloadable.java:49) ~[launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.popAndDownload(DownloadJob.java:108) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob.access$000(DownloadJob.java:12) [launcher.jar:?]
    at net.minecraft.launcher.updater.download.DownloadJob$1.run(DownloadJob.java:89) [launcher.jar:?]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_40]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_40]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.7.0_40]
[16:33:33 ERROR]: Gave up trying to download https://libraries.minecraft.net/org/lwjgl/lwjgl/lwjgl_util/2.9.1-nightly-20131120/lwjgl_util-2.9.1-nightly-20131120.jar for job 'Version & Libraries'
[16:33:33 ERROR]: Job 'Version & Libraries' finished with 26 failure(s)! (took 0:00:50.083)
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Are you getting this error when starting the Bukkit server or when you're starting the client?

Comment: when i start the Clinet

Comment: when i press " Play " Button it start loading and eventually nothing happen and  the game not start and the error come - if you press Development Console -

Comment: Wait, what version are you running?  Minecraft shouldn't be trying to download stuff minecraft.net, it should be trying to get it from an Amazon S3 instance.  That's probably why the socket is timing out.

Comment: @MBraedley isn't it the other way around? I thought Mojang ditched amazon's servers.

Comment: @aman207 you might be right.  I haven't stayed fully up to date with that stuff.

Answer (score -1):

Restart your computer, close firewalls and then start Minecraft. That worked for me.